# Hybrid New Keynesian philips curve model - inflation expectation

Tags: inflation, rational-expectations, expectations, gmm

I am doing research on the HNKPC model following Gali and Gertler 1999 as per the picture. I do not understand how to get the inflation expectations. Could I get more insight on how to perform this model using the inflation expectations by using VAR.

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304393299000239

As per the equation on the NKPC, there is the term for the expected inflation, (t+1).

I want to know, what is this value based on?
Recent literature uses professional surveys, however I am not sure about other methods to use for this proxy. 
Is this value an average of the past inflation, or can it be calculated through other variables? Can you give more insight on what to use for this variable.